# "Unarm" vs. "disarm"

Tags: differences, verbs

Is there a semantic difference?

I thought *unarm* was more popular, but [Google Ngram shows otherwise](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=unarm,disarm&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3).

Comment: Almost all the NGram instances for *unarm* are actually quoting *much* earlier usage, or are the archaic/poetic *unarm'd*. As a current synonym for *disarm*, it's well below the radar, if it's actually used at all in that sense nowadays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to me the use of *unarm* as a transitive verb (to *deprive someone of weapons*, or to *lay down one's own weapons*) is at the very least archaic usage. [Here's](http://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/views/plays/play_view.php?WorkID=troilus&Act=5&Scene=3&Scope=scene) an instance from Shakespeare's *Troilus and Cressida*.

*Unarm* survives mainly as the past participle *unarmed*, meaning *not carrying any weapons (particularly firearms)*.

The standard term for taking someone's weapons is to *disarm*, which carries much the same sense as in *disarming a bomb*, meaning to disable the detonator mechanism so it won't explode.

There is also the figurative use as in *a disarming smile*, where the sense is that one's potential hostility melts away in the face of a charming appearance or friendly behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

The only dictionary that has "**unarm**" with the meaning of "*To empty or strip of arms*" is the OED and it gives it as *Obsolete*. Another one that has it is the [FreeDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unarm) that defines it as a less common word for *disarm* and mainly used in the military.

In the [OALD](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/unarmed+%7C22%7C) and in the NOAD, you can only find the adjective "*unarmed*" which means "not carrying weapons", used like this:

> *He was shooting unarmed civilians.*

**Disarm** is the verb that appears in both (see the [OALD](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/disarm) again) which relatively to this question, means "*to take a weapon or weapons away from somebody*":

> *Most of the rebels were captured and disarmed.*

Answer (score 0):

"Unarm" is when you don't have any weapons on you.

> I came to the party unarmed.

"Dismarmed" is when you had weapons, but they *made* you "unarmed", that is, they took it away.

"Disarmed" has an additional meaning of taking away your defense, as in:

> Her smile completely disarmed me...

Answer (score 0):

As reported by the NOAD, *unarm* is a verb meaning "deprive or free (someone) of arms or armour."
One of the meaning of *disarm* is the following one:

> take a weapon or weapons away from (a person, force, or country)
>    • (of a country or force) give up or reduce its armed forces or weapons
>    • remove the fuse from a bomb, making it safe.